# .Net Core Console App Logging feature - why does my Console.WriteLine appear outside start and end logging?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Found this [article](https://thecodebuzz.com/logging-in-net-core-console-application/) on .Net Core logging in a console app.

It's seems to work but I don't know why my Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff"); appears outside of the start and end logging messages.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(services);
            using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                MyApplication app = serviceProvider.GetService<MyApplication>();
                // Start up logic here
                app.Run();
            }
        }
        private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
            .AddTransient<MyApplication>();
        }
    }

    public class MyApplication
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public MyApplication(ILogger<MyApplication> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        internal void Run()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Application Started at {dateTime}", DateTime.UtcNow);

            //Business Logic START

            Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");
            //Business logic END
            _logger.LogInformation("Application Ended at {dateTime}", DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `ILogger`? `Console.WriteLine` comes first before your logger is doing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Because the [ConsoleLogger](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/b454c5a67eeecd388095519dc576944b4434ead0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLogger.cs) class in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` queues the message.

It's eventually processed and printed out to the console on a background thread by an [internal logger processor](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/b454c5a67eeecd388095519dc576944b4434ead0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/Internal/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs).

`Console.WriteLine` writes directly to the console.